# How can I add a tooltip/popover to table data using Angular2 and Bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular

Please bear with me if I sound a little inexperienced (I am), but I'm currently trying to add a tooltip or a popover (either one, doesn't matter) to a td using Angular2 and Bootstrap to ultimately get rid of an unnecessary column. I would like the popover or tooltip to open on hover rather than on click. I've tried installing the ng2-popover module via nodejs as was recommended on another post on here, but to no avail. Here's a simplified version of the beginning of my table:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
<tbody><tr>
<th>Table Name</th>
<th> Max As Of Date </th>
<th> Row Count for Date</th>
<th> Comments </th><th>
<td> Table Data </td>
```

The original guy who recommended to someone else to use the ng2-popover module rather than JQuery suggested the following:

```
<span popover="content to be shown in the popover">
element on which this popover is applied.
</span>
```

However that didn't work for me when I put a td in there. Thank you in advance if you have any clue how to do this!

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the 
angular's bootstrap: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tooltip

already has `tooltip` feature adapted for **angular**.

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : !inputModel}">
      <label>Disable tooltips conditionally:</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="inputModel" class="form-control"
             placeholder="Hover over this for a tooltip until this is filled"
             uib-tooltip="Enter something in this input field to disable this tooltip"
             tooltip-placement="top"
             tooltip-trigger="mouseenter"
             tooltip-enable="!inputModel" />
    </div>
```

> Just adding the **directive** like:
>
> **uib-tooltip**: text to display 
>   **tooltip-placement**: place or where will the text will be positioned 
>   **tooltip-trigger**: what will make the text appears (can be any event)

Here an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)